# Searching for Tweets with Unicode Character / Apple Emoji?

Tags: twitter

I am compiling a corpus of Tweets for sentiment analysis and am trying to grab Tweets with Apple Emoji characters.

I have found the unicode character for one of the faces as: U+1F604 (U+D83D U+DE04), UTF-8: F0 9F 98 84

So far, I haven't been able to get any meaningful results.  If I search `\ud83d\ude04` I'll get some Tweets back, but nothing useful.  `\U0001f604` doesn't return anything on search.

Is there any way for me to query Twitter for these characters?

I am using the python-twitter wrapper for the API, but would be willing to use something else if a better alternative exists.

Comment: I know this is possible as http://www.iemoji.com/ has a stream of tweets that contain emoji, raising a bounty.

Answer (score 5):

As @Terence Eden points out, twitters REST search api doesn't work with emoji characters, but the streaming API does (as of Jan 2016).

There are a few tools out there for accessing twitters APIs in python. The one I've mostly used it `tweepy`. It can be installed with `pip`.

The [tweepy docs on setting up the streaming api](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/streaming_how_to.html) are quite easy to follow. The strings you filter on need to contain the actual emoji characters (e.g.: '').

Note that this searches for emojis as "words": that is, surrounded by white space. Something like "free" won't be found!

Comment: Very strange. I noticed this myself. Any idea why streaming can do it but not searching? Anyway, this answer should've been accepted by the OP.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible - but it's slightly tricky....

You can't use the standard Twitter search - but you can use the Streaming Search.

There are open source libraries available at https://github.com/mroth/emojitrack-feeder in Ruby and Node.